How to securely conduct lottery-like draws with guaranteed randomness without auditing?
Is there an existing algorithm or method to conduct lottery-like draws that ensures secure and truly random results without the need for auditing?

There are any lib to do this?
I search on the web and don't find nothing about it.

How to do this kind of lottery-like draws?

In its current form, this is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow for at least these reasons: 1) it needs more focus, 2) it's asking for off-site recommendations, and 3) at least part of the question is not about programming. Please edit your question to correct these issues.

(cit.) : "Anyone who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin." -- John Von Neumann (1951)

https://www.americanscientist.org/sites/americanscientist.org/files/20144141249210337-2014-05TechnologueFp170.jpg

Please define "without auditing" and "truly random".  Do you mean verifying the algorithm (which presumably requires some thought to determine correctness) or do you mean ongoing work to ensure draws produced by the algorithm remain unpredictable for everyone (or whatever definition you happen to be using for "truly random").
